# Loop textboxes and cells

Tags: loops

I need some help making this code shorter. I have a lot of textboxes with times in my form which I want to copy to my Excel file. Some of the boxes needed to be 15min less in Excel sheet and I want to loop through these textboxes and and copy the result into the correct cell. My code works but I want to make it for more textboxes at once.

```vba
Dim d1re1 As Date = TextBox5.Text
TextBox5.Text = d1re1.ToLongTimeString()
Dim d1nre1 As Date = d1re1.AddMinutes(-15)
xlsp1.Cells(7, 100) = d1nre1.ToLongTimeString

Dim d1re2 As Date = TextBox7.Text
TextBox7.Text = d1re2.ToLongTimeString()
Dim d1nre2 As Date = d1re2.AddMinutes(-15)
xlsp1.Cells(7, 102) = d1nre2.ToLongTimeString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here that the lines somehow doing the same but with different parameters.
Here functions come in the picture. You can just create generic method call it for ex : SetDateToFieldscand takes the parameters : the source textbox and which cell it needs to update.

Like this you just need only to call the method with different params.

Comment: tnx for your answer. Im still learning vb so could you give me an example of a function the way you meant.

Comment: You need to learn method syntax and Here an example to pass the Textbox http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?221724-Passing-a-textbox-as-a-function-parameter    ... Dont forget to mark as answered :)) ..